# Max Contribution to IRA, Roth, and Both

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, contribution, limits

Question: I am looking for maximum allowed contribution to

- Traditional IRA
- Roth IRA
- Traditional IRA and Roth IRA combined

Searched IRS, and it is confusing

[Website](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits) says

> For 2015, 2016, and 2017, your total contributions to all of your traditional and Roth IRAs cannot be more than:
>
> $5,500 ($6,500 if you’re age 50 or older), or
>
> your taxable compensation for the year, if your compensation was less than this dollar limit.

When they say `your total contributions` do they mean combined traditional and Roth IRA, or do they mean traditional, separate, Roth separate?

I continued searching IRS website, and I cannot find answer I am looking for. Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When they say your total contributions do they mean combined
>   traditional and Roth IRA, or do they mean traditional, separate, Roth
>   separate?

Yes, they mean that the amount you contribute to Traditional IRA that year, *plus* the amount you contribute to Roth IRA that year, cannot exceed that number.

Comment: Then what if I wish to contribute to only Traditional IRA or only Roth IRA. Is there a limit for each individual contribution (which naturally adds up to `$5,500`). Or there is no such limit for individual IRA types, anyone can contribute say, `$1` to Traditional and `$5,499` to ROTH. Please clarify.

Comment: @Rhonda: Yes, if your IRA broker allows contributions as low as $1, you could contribute $1 to Traditional IRA and $5499 to Roth IRA.

Comment: Caveat: IF you have fairly **high income** (this year $184k joint or $117k single, adjusts for inflation) your Roth limit is reduced or eliminated entirely, but you can still contribute to a traditional IRA and _convert_ it to Roth as soon as you like, even immediately; this is usually called 'backdoor Roth' and discussed in other Qs here and many other places.